# incorrect outputs in two arrays C

Tags: c, function, output

When I try to fill two arrays the output is incorrect, but when I try to fill one array that works correctly, I can't find the error, I also tried using pointers

Two Arrays: Wrong output

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1

int fillArrays(int a[], int b[]);

int main() {
    int a[MAX], b[MAX], i;

    fillArrays(a, b);
    showArrays(a, b);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int fillArrays(int a[], int b[]) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
          printf("a[%d]: ", i);
          scanf("%d", &a[i]); 
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
          printf("b[%d]: ", i);
          scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
}

int showArrays(int a[], int b[]) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
          printf("%d", a[i]); //incorrect output
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++) {
          printf("%d", b[i]); //incorrect output
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output you expect, what is the output you want. Update your question by editing it (and don't use the word **Edit** or **Update, the site has edit history) and include this information.

Comment: For questions like these asking for help in fixing bugs, you need to show us your input, your output, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Arrays in C are 0 indexed.

That means, the index of the **beginning** of the array will be `0`, and the **last** element of the array will be `size_of_array - 1`.

In your `showArrays()`,
you try to access elements of the arrays `a[]` and `b[]` *which are not part of the array*.

Hence, you need to change the terminating condition of your every `for` loop from `i <= MAX` to `i < MAX`.

Modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1

int fillArrays(int a[], int b[]);

int main() {
    int a[MAX], b[MAX], i;

    fillArrays(a, b);
    showArrays(a, b);

    getch();
    return 0;
}

int fillArrays(int a[], int b[]) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
          printf("a[%d]: ", i);
          scanf("%d", &a[i]); 
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
          printf("b[%d]: ", i);
          scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }
}

int showArrays(int a[], int b[]) {
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
          printf("%d", a[i]); 
    }

    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
          printf("%d", b[i]); 
    }
}
```

---

<sup>Accessing elements *out of bounds* of an array results in undefined behavior.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
```

to

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
```

The bug is that you have declared the array of length `1` and trying to access the index `1` (a[1]).

Instead you have to count the index from `0` to `N-1` where `N` is the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems to be working fine for me, but here's what I think is wrong:

You've defined an array of length 1 (`int a[1]`), but your `for` loop iterates through 2 times, reading a[0] and a[1]. One of these doesn't exist, because a is length 1! My compiler tidied it up for me, but don't count on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
 for(i = 0; i <=MAX; i++)
```

Write Like

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
```

Your array length is 1. The array is start with 0 and end with length-1.

Answer (score 0):

When you are declare the array as a[1], you can only store the single value on the array.you are declared the two arrays.

It will allocate the memory continuously.like

```
   |  4bytes  |  4bytes  |                         |
   a          b                                    n.
```

a and b take each 4 bytes, so when we are assign the value is a[1], it will refer the address of b[0], and when you are locating b[1], it will locate the next empty space.

So when you tried to print the a[1] - it will print the value of b[0], it is refers as the undefined behaviour also.

Answer (score 0):

you allocated the array size is one so you can store only one values in that array but in the for loop you get two input for array so first input take a[0] and send input take b[0]. But in that for loop you are getting two input for one array that is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain it in a simple way from the basics.
When you create an array like

```
int array[2];
```

you get an array with indices `0` and `1` ( an array with 2 indices ) . In other words,
`array[0]` and `array[1]`

In your code, `Max` is 1, which means the array can only store 1 value, namely, in the position `a[0]` and `b[0]`. ( in the index `Max - 1` )

But in your for loop, you have the condition

```
for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
```

This loop continues as long as `i` is `<=` `Max`. In other words, the loop is exited when `i` becomes `2`. So you try to fill an array which can only hold one value with two values, causing array out of bounds which can lead to undefined behavior ( Undefined Behavior is impossible to predict and the result will depend on your compiler, so it's hard for someone to predict what might happen ) .

To solve this, you just have to change your for loop condition to

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
```

Well, hope you understood your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If an array is declared as having `MAX` elements then the valid range of its indices is `0 : MAX - 1` provided that MAX is not equal to 0. So in your example as MAX is equal to 1 then the array has only one element and valid index to access this element is 0.

Thus instead of the loop

```
for(i = 0; i <= MAX; i++)
```

you have to write

```
for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
```

that is equivalent to

```
for(i = 0; i < 1; i++)
```

and only variable i with value 0 will be used as the index.

Take into account that neither function returns a value. So the return type of the functions should be `void`.

Also you should declare function `showArrays`before its using the same way as you declared function `fillArrays`. As inside the function the arrays are not changed then the function could be declared like

```
void showArrays(const int a[], const int b[]);
```

Also according to the C Standard relative to the function main

> It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:

```
int main(void) { /* ... */ }
```

not

```
int main() { /* ... */ }
```